# What to use spring Restcontroller or RepositoryRestResource

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

I need produce Rest Api with spring HAL hateoas support and pagination.
What I see is if I use @Restcontroller I need manually write code for _links and paging logic.

If I use RepositoryRestResource we can get generated links and pagination but I don't have control on _link generation and API path, I don't know I can customize or not.

So how can we use @restcontroller and RepositoryRestResource together so that I can use pagination of repository rest resource and API path of rest controller

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using @RepositoryRestResource on your repository, follow the points to achieve what you have mentioned,

1. Extend your repository with [org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) which is going to provide pagination stuff, you just need to pass **page** and **size** in request parameters to get that work.
2. Customization of API path can be done using @RestResource(path = "your_path_to_api") on top of the method defined in your repository.